# Access Eloquent's one to one relation on the WRITE connection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

There is a case in my app, where I need to force the database WRITE connection when accessing a relation. How can I do it?

**Models**

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the phone record associated with the user.
     */
    public function phone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Phone');
    }
}

class Phone extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user that owns the phone.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Now, I've got this code:

```
$user = $request->user();

if ($user && $user->phone) {
    // do something...
}
```

Now, I need to force WRITE on this: `$user->phone`.

I know there's the **[onWriteConnection()](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_onWriteConnection)** method, however it returns a `Builder` object, on which I cannot use the `->phone` relation.

Any idea how I can force something like this below?

```
// Warning: pseudo code!
if ($user && $user->onWriteConnection()->phone) {/*...*/}
```

Comment: Since onWriteConnection() return a builder, Haven't you try something like ```User::onWriteConnection()->first()->phone```  ?

Comment: Try `User::onWriteConnection()->find($user->id)->phone` ?

Comment: Jesse de gans nailed it. This definitely works. Is it the only possible way? Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple Connection then try to use this.
For example:

```
'read' => [
    'host' => '192.168.1.1',
],
'write' => [
    'host' => '196.168.1.2'
],
$user = DB::connection('write')->select(...);
```

Comment: Yep, that I know of. It's an alternative. I'm just wondering if I can do the same directly on Eloquent relation.

Comment: add connection property in model. Example 
    **protected $connection = 'connection-name';**

Comment: Sure. But I need to use the WRITE connection in one specific case only. Can I specify the connection on request basis?